# What is the correct way to vertically align in this circumstance?

Tags: html, css, vertical-alignment

Aligning things vertically seems like a dark art. This is a section of my currect sites code (specifically, the header). The site is coded like this to do with the footer being docked to the bottom of the page.

**HTML:**

```
<div id="header-wrap" class="full_width">
  <div id="header-container" class="dc1">
    <div id="header" class="thin_width rel">
      <a href="/"><img src="/static/img/header.jpg" id="logo" alt="coming soon" title="coming soon"></a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="/posts/list/">Link 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="/posts/create/">Link 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="/about">Link 3</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#header-wrap { top: 0; left: 0; }
#header-container { height: 60px; border-bottom: 1px solid #E5E5E5; }
#header { margin: 0 auto; }
#header h1 { color: #beffbf; text-align: left; width: 290px; margin: 0; position: absolute; left: 0; top: 20px; }
#header h1 em { color: #90b874; font-size: small; display: block; }
#header ul { margin: 0; padding: 0; list-style: none; position: absolute; top: 35px; right: 0; }
#header ul li { float: left; margin-right: 5px; }
#header ul li a{ color: #90b874; font-weight: bold; font-size: 1.4em; margin-right: 5px; text-decoration: none; }
#header ul li a:hover { color: #beffbf;  }
.dc1 { background-color: #FFFFFF; }
.rel { position: relative; }
.full_width { width: 100%; }
.thin_width { width: 450px; }​
```

[Here's a JSFiddle Exmple](http://jsfiddle.net/AHsBN/)

How should I go about trying to vertically align the links on the right and the logo?
I would like to try and do this without using fixed padding since it makes it a pain if I ever update the logo or link height.

So, what is the correct way to vertically align in this circumstance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need to do is set element.style

`#header ul { top:0;}` and #header `{ position: relative;}`

Comment: It didnt work, im afraid. I did that here, but it top aligned it
http://jsfiddle.net/AHsBN/4/

Comment: Ok, if you want them allign to middle here you go `#header-container {line-height: 60px;}`

Comment: But in that case you need to change line-height according to logo height. If it's fixed then it's a perfect solution, if it's not then it's not a good way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

`display:table-cell` works well for this

```
#header-wrap { top: 0; left: 0; }
#header-container { height: 60px; border-bottom: 1px solid #E5E5E5; display:table-cell; vertical-align:middle; }
#header { margin:0 auto; overflow:auto;}
```

Check the demo http://jsfiddle.net/AHsBN/2/

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution, no positioning, heights and such are needed, just adjust the vertical-align as you wish to either, top, middle, bottom or baseline etc (I used height: 300px for `#header-container` to more easily illustrate `vertical-align: middle;`

```
#header > a { background: red; }
ul { background: green; }
#header-container { background: blue; height: 300px; }

#header > a, ul { display: block; }
li { display: inline-block; }
#header > a { float: left; }
ul { float: right; font-size: 200%; }
#header-container { display: table; width: 100%; }
#header { display: table-cell; vertical-align: middle; }
```

Also no need to clear the floats as its within a CSS table.

Answer (score 0):

**HTML**

```
<div id="header">
    <a href="./" class="logo"><img src="http://www.google.co.in/images/srpr/logo3w.png" alt=""></a>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="/posts/list/">Link 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="/posts/create/">Link 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="/about">Link 3</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#header { position: relative; background: #ddd; }
#header a.logo {display: inline-block; vertical-align: middle; *display: inline; zoom: 1;}
#header ul { display: inline-block; vertical-align: middle; *display: inline; zoom: 1; position: absolute; right: 0px; top: 50%; height: 20px;}
#header ul li { display: inline; position: relative; top: -50%;  }
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/gZceQ/4/

Code above should work in all browsers :)